# Angular 2 - Parent Component Couldn't Receive the EventEmitter from the Child Component

Tags: angular

I have a object I want to emit from the child component to the parent component. But the parent component is not picking up that object from the child. In the parent method, I added a console.log in the parent method, onChangeCriteria, to check if this method is being called, but it didn't. Could anyone help?

**Child Component**

```
export class CriteriaComponent implements OnInit {
  years: string[] = [];
  facilities: any;

  // this object variable maintain the state of the selected quarter, year, and company.
  criteria = {
    quarter: 0,
    year: 0,
    company: 0
  }

  @Output() criteriaEvent = new EventEmitter();
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // private functions
  getYearsList() {
    let thisYear: number = (new Date().getFullYear()) + 1; // get next year
    let arrYears: string[] = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      arrYears.push((thisYear - x).toString());
    }

    return arrYears;
  }

  // build and update the criterion object
  criteraOnChange(e: any) {
    var field = e.target.id;
    var value = e.target.value;
    
    switch (field) {
      case 'quarters': this.criteria.quarter = value;
        break;
      case 'years': this.criteria.year = value;
        break;
      case 'companies': this.criteria.company = value;
        break;
    }
    
    // do not emit if the criteria are not complete.
    if (this.criteria.quarter == 0 || this.criteria.year == 0 || this.criteria.company == 0) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(this.criteria);
    this.criteriaEvent.emit(this.criteria);
  }
}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<header>
    <app-navigation></app-navigation>
</header>
<main>
    <section>
        <div class="container mt-3">
            <app-criteria (criteriaEvent)="onChangeCriteria($event)"></app-criteria>
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
            <app-section></app-section>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

**Parent Component TS**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = '';
  result: any;

  constructor() { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
        
  }

  onChangeCriteria(criteria: any) {
    console.log(criteria);
  }
}
```

I expect the browser will console the object being emitted by the child. But it didn't console anything. I have made sure, I have the @Output() and the EventEmitter all configure properly, and bind the output to the parent's function.

Comment: Are you sure the `criteraOnChange` from the child is not stopping at the `if ` statement?  It is also a good idea to provide a minimum reproducible problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Yes I have added a console.log statement right after the IF statement, and it consoles the criteria object.

Comment: Double check where you're importing EventEmitter from. Is CriteriaComponent as *direct* child of AppComponent? Do you get type errors if you specify types more clearly e.g.  `onChangeCriteria(criteria: Criteria)`  with `type Criteria = { quarter: number, year: number, company: number }`,